# Post-policy politics...what?

Tags: expressions, politics

I have to translate a Washington Post article on Trump but I cannot understand one part:

> It's **post-policy politics**. It's about having the right feelings instead of the right proposals. Now, that doesn't mean that we shouldn't point out when he's contradicting himself or when his plans don't add up. But it does mean that we should probably be a little less credulous about this supposed policy pivot or that change in message.
>   There has to be one for that to happen.

Comment: No one understands Trump

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! This question would be better suited to either, if you're questioning the political meaning of *post-policy politics*, [Politics.SE](http://politics.stackexchange.com) or if you want help translating it, our sister site [English Language Learners.SE](http://ell.stackexchange.com). Whichever way you opt, this question is not best suited to this site.

Comment: "Post-policy" means "in the era after policy was considered relevant" -- the politics are not about actual policy anymore, just the sounds that one makes.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase

> post *X Y*

applies to a situation or environment *Y* in which the consideration *X* no longer applies. Thus in a discussion of the Cold War, you might find the phrase

> post war [often postwar] Europe

which refers to Europe after the end of World War II. After the election of Barack Obama, there was much talk about the

> post racial society

as though race, the most intractable division within American society, was no longer an important factor in public life once a black man had been elected President. The expression

> post policy politics

may be understood in the same way -- a consideration of American political life in which the differences between politicians and political parties do not depend on positions on issues but rather on emotion.

Answer (score 2):

It's explained in the following sentence.

Post-policy politics: *It's about having the right feelings instead of the right proposals.*

Answer (score 1):

Oversimplifying from a historical point of view, one can understand "**post-policy politics**" as follows. Prior to Trump, politics in the U.S. in recent times has been based on differences in the policy positions of the two principal political parties. With the appearance of Trump, whom some consider not to have put forward any clear, coherent, and consistent policy positions, the 2016 presidential election is not being waged as a battle between competing policy positions but as a battle between policy positions on the part of Clinton and something else on the part of Trump. Some might characterize this "something else" as emotion, but it could be nationalism, racism, xenophobia, or ... not that these lack an emotional component. In any event, this development represents a major departure from past practice, and perhaps, according to some, even the end of policy-based politics as we've known it. So, going forward, one could argue that politics in the future will be based not on the consideration of policies and policy differences, but on "something else". One could call the politics of this brave new world **post-policy politics**.

I consider **post-policy politics** a bit of misnomer. It certainly doesn't have the clarity of "post-war Europe" (to borrow from @deadrat's answer). The problem is **post-policy** -- what does it mean? The war ended, so we can speak intelligibly of "post-war" Europe. But I don't see "policy", which is much fuzzier, as having the same kind of natural endpoint. The following would make more sense, although I'm sure there are many other understandable options: **post policy-based-politics** or **post policy-based politics**. The hyphen in **post-policy** has to go (@deadrat omitted it).

Comment: Could you please set mentions in italic not bold?

Comment: @tchrist Okay. Sure. Is there a style manual somewhere?

Comment: [This meta post is regarding italics on ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/363/what-emphasis-to-use-when-referring-to-words/444#444)